# Slow performance on low memory - Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, swift

Been trying to find this bug for days now with no solution. Developing a ios game uising swift and only UIKit. My app displays a lot of small images (about 70 a time). Some uianimations are running repeatingly. After a while my app show some performance lags (tested on a device). Xcode shows only 30MB of memory usage and about 97% CPU time used. Using instruments didnt really help (im not using a lot of memory anyway). How can I track this bug down, this seems so weird to me.

Comment: I also made the same mistake, try using SpriteKit is will handle way better. The physics are better to!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that using UIKit for such graphics is not the best solution, as it is working through CPU, not GPU. And this is the reason, why application is lagging.
The other reason for it to show only 30MB of memory used, as it does not show memory used for uncompressed images. When you display image on the screen, or use UIViews with drawRect:, it takes really a lot of memory.